# Missing SQL row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the sample table I'm using and I'm trying to find non duplicate rows in the table:

```
 ID status_old  status_new  assign  Pre_status  S_TIMESTAMP                 S_TIMESTAMP_next
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234    NULL    A            NULL   B           7/13/2021  12:19:06 PM      7/13/2021  12:19:22 PM
1234    A       B            NULL   C           7/13/2021  12:19:22 PM      7/13/2021  12:19:22 PM
1234    B       C            NULL   C           7/13/2021  12:19:22 PM      7/13/2021  12:19:23 PM
1234    C       C            NULL   C           7/13/2021  12:19:23 PM      7/13/2021  12:20:24 PM
1234    C       C            NULL   D           7/13/2021  12:20:24 PM      7/13/2021  12:37:03 PM
1234    C       D            NULL   D           7/13/2021  12:37:03 PM      7/13/2021  12:37:09 PM
1234    D       D            NULL   D           7/13/2021  12:37:09 PM      7/13/2021  1:02:01 PM
1234    D       D            555    D           7/13/2021  1:02:01 PM       7/13/2021  1:02:07 PM
1234    D       D            555    E           7/13/2021  1:02:07 PM       7/13/2021  2:59:40 PM
1234    D       E            555    E           7/13/2021  2:59:40 PM       7/13/2021  3:00:26 PM
1234    E       E            555    E           7/13/2021  3:00:26 PM       7/18/2021  5:57:38 PM
1234    E       E            555    F           7/18/2021  5:57:38 PM       7/18/2021  5:59:55 PM
1234    E       F            555    NULL        7/18/2021  5:59:55 PM       null
```

I wrote these SQL queries to filter the rows and display the non duplicated row

```
INSERT INTO #sub_tableY (ID, status_old, status_new, assign, pre_status, S_TIMESTAMP, S_TIMESTAMP_next)
    SELECT  
        ID, status_old, status_new, assig,
        LEAD(status_new, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY S_TIMESTAMP) pre_status, 
        S_TIMESTAMP,
        LEAD(S_TIMESTAMP, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY S_TIMESTAMP) S_TIMESTAMP_next
    FROM 
        TABLE
    WHERE
        (status_old != status_new OR status_old IS NULL)
        AND (assign IS NULL OR assign IS NOT NULL)
    GROUP BY
        ID, status_old, status_new, S_TIMESTAMP, assign, pre_status
```

This is the result I get:

```
 ID status_old  status_new  assign  Pre_status  S_TIMESTAMP             S_TIMESTAMP_next
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234    NULL    A           NULL    B           7/13/2021  12:19:06 PM  7/13/2021  12:19:22 PM
1234    A       B           NULL    C           7/13/2021  12:19:22 PM  7/13/2021  12:19:22 PM
1234    B       C           NULL    D           7/13/2021  12:19:22 PM  7/13/2021  12:37:03 PM
1234    C       D           NULL    E           7/13/2021  12:37:03 PM  7/13/2021  2:59:40 PM
1234    D       E           555     F           7/13/2021  2:59:40 PM   7/18/2021  5:57:38 PM
1234    E       F           555     NULL        7/18/2021  5:57:38 PM   NULL
```

but I expecting the this as result:

```
ID status_old   status_new  assign  Pre_status  S_TIMESTAMP             S_TIMESTAMP_next
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234    NULL    A           NULL    B           7/13/2021  12:19:06 PM  7/13/2021  12:19:22 PM
1234    A       B           NULL    C           7/13/2021  12:19:22 PM  7/13/2021  12:19:22 PM
1234    B       C           NULL    D           7/13/2021  12:19:22 PM  7/13/2021  12:37:03 PM
1234    C       D           NULL    D           7/13/2021  12:37:03 PM  7/13/2021  1:02:01 PM
>1234   D       D           555     E           7/13/2021  1:02:01 PM   7/13/2021  2:59:40 PM
1234    D       E           555     F           7/13/2021  2:59:40 PM   7/18/2021  5:57:38 PM
1234    E       F           555     NULL        7/18/2021  5:57:38 PM   NULL
```

I'm expecting the query to include the row that contain the assign value for first time

```
1234    D       D           555     E           7/13/2021  1:02:01 PM   7/13/2021  2:59:40 PM
```

but it's not displayed with my current query

Comment: If you add your sample data as DDL+DML you make it **much** easier for people to assist.

Comment: `assign IS NULL OR assign IS NOT NULL` is always going to be true btw.

Comment: Can you explain the dedupe logic in your question? It's hard to tell by looking at your code

Comment: The where clause requires `status_old != status_new` but the "missing" row has values `D D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LAG` to grab the value of `assign` from the previous row and compare it to the current row. That way you can detect when it changes:

```
SELECT  
    ID, status_old, status_new, assig,
    LEAD(status_new, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY S_TIMESTAMP) 
      as pre_status, 
    S_TIMESTAMP,
    LEAD(S_TIMESTAMP, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY S_TIMESTAMP)
      as S_TIMESTAMP_next
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE
    (status_old != status_new OR status_old IS NULL)
      OR (
        ISNULL(assign,0) <>
          LAG(ISNULL(assign,0), 1, -1) OVER(ORDER BY S_TIMESTAMP)
      )
GROUP BY
    ID, status_old, status_new, S_TIMESTAMP, assign, pre_status
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Should that where clause be OR instead of AND? hmm.

Comment: I changed it to OR.